# How do I dynamically change the cell size of a Grid Layout Group component in Unity when developing for Android?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 2017.4.6f1 and I have a question about the cell size of Grid Layout Group among UI elements.

[image]

Currently, I was developing to 1080x1920 resolution, and I set the cell size to 200px and the spacing to 15px respectively. I set the resolution at 9:16 aspect ratio instead of the fixed resolution one day.

[image]
This is the intended result picture from 1080x1920 resolution.

[image]
This is an unintended result picture from a 9:16 aspect ratio.

How do you get your results to work as you originally intended for Android games? I would like to make the Cell Size correspond to all resolutions, just like the dp coding in Android development.

Answer (score 0):

How about Change "Canvas Scaler" - UI scale Mode in you scene as "scale with screen size".

here some reference in unity docs.

https://docs.unity3d.com/kr/530/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html